# Creating a Platform in sprite-kit

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics

How would I make a sprite so that an object would be able to move through the bottom of it, but bounce off the top? as opposed to just being bounced off from any contact.

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a 'jump' state check for your sprite,and while he is moving up turn off collision checking for the platform on your sprite, then when falling down, reenable it.  You may have to add a check for whether or not the sprite is inside a platform though, because the physics will get you if you enable it while inside.

Comment: I second this. probably you would have to check the velocity.

Comment: yeah,  that is probably what I would do depending on what this game actually is,  just override the velocity variable and do some other management

Answer (score 0):

You could create two nodes of the same width that are stacked on each other (therefore looking like one). Give their physicsBody a different categoryBitMask and contactTestBitMask to differentiate them.

Now check for collisions and buffer them in a simple list. If you now handle the collisions just check which collision occured first: The collision with the upper or lower node? Then you know whether you need to add force (i.e., bounce) that object or not. :)